# MFC application crashes on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mfc

I have an MFC application that works on XP and crashes on Windows 7. (I don't have the source - this is a 3rd-party application that the 3rd-party no longer supports; I'm just trying to get the darn thing to run).

Most of the application works, but there is one screen (MDI window) that contains a ton of controls (worst UI ever), including 3 ComboBox controls. Simply moving the mouse over those controls (which are in the contracted state) causes the application to crash with the error "MFC application has stopped working".

From what I can determine using Spy++, the controls are standard ComboBox window classes. They're subclassed of course, and I assume that whatever processing takes place in response to the mouse-over message is causing the fault.

I was kinda hoping that running it in XP compatibility mode would help, but it doesn't.

What sort of thing would cause this to fail on Windows 7 when it worked OK on XP? (Some other parts of the application failed because some DLLs were missing, and I was able to fix that by copying the DLLs from the older environment. I was kinda hoping that this might be something similar).

PS. The old environment had Office 2003, and the new one has Office 2010. While this thing isn't really related to Office, I mention that in case it's relevant somehow.

Comment: Can't you get a crash dump and make some post-mortem investigation?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the software as administrator. My guess is that the software tries to write some kind of log/temporary file to `C:\Windows\` or `C:\Program Files\`. Perhaps the application assumes a valid file pointer when opening a file for writing?

If it works, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to determine which file it tries to open. Then give full permissions to this folder/file and see if it works in normal mode.

### UPDATE

If hovering the controls produces a crash I would bet that you are using some kind of Skin Manager to get some kind of nice-looking UI. Skinning involves advanced hooking and/or API hijacking. Such techniques are not guaranteed to work on future versions of Windows.

I know that older versions of Codejock SkinManager did crash on Windows Vista and later. If that is the library you're using I suggest you upgrade it to the latest version or simply disable it completely.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. To be honest, I very much doubt that it's trying to do any file IO, since (a) that'd be a very strange thing to do in response to a mouse-over event in a combobox, and (b) failing to access a file seems unlikely to cause a hard crash which is what I'm experiencing.

Comment: Five years later. Cool!